# Foreign key issue in SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 

Tags: sql-server-ce

I'm new to SQL Server CE.

When I'm trying to create table with foreign and primary key relation I'm getting error.
Could you please let me know whats wrong with my code.

```
CREATE TABLE ACTIVECALLS
    (CallID int PRIMARY KEY,
     EPName nvarchar PRIMARY KEY,
     ConsoleName nvarchar,
     DispatcherName nvarchar,
     EmergencyCall bit,
     CallDirectionId tinyint foreign key references CallDirection(CallDirectionId), 
     CallStateId tinyint foreign key references CallState(CallStateId)
    );
```

Comment: Don't know how CE 3.5 works - but you if define `NVARCHAR` column - you **should specify a length!**. Otherwise it'll default to 1 character long.... so use `NVARCHAR(50)` instead of just `NVARCHAR` ....

Answer (score 0):

```
CREATE TABLE  ACTIVECALLS(

CallID int PRIMARY KEY,
EPName nvarchar(50) PRIMARY KEY,
ConsoleName nvarchar(50,
DispatcherName nvarchar(50),
EmergencyCall bit,
CallDirectionId tinyint references CallDirection(CallDirectionId ), 
CallStateId tinyint references CallState(CallStateId));
```